# Cannot convert type 'CustomPrincipal' to 'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal'

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, iprincipal

I have followed this [guide](http://peterbromberg.net/post/Implementing-a-Custom-IPrincipal-in-an-ASPNET-MVC-Application.aspx) to add custom properies to IPrincipal.

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            CustomPrincipalSerializeModel serializeModel = serializer.Deserialize<CustomPrincipalSerializeModel>(authTicket.UserData);
            CustomPrincipal newUser = new CustomPrincipal(authTicket.Name);
            newUser.UserId = serializeModel.UserId;
            newUser.FirstName = serializeModel.FirstName;
            newUser.LastName = serializeModel.LastName;
            HttpContext.Current.User = newUser; /This line makes an error.
        }
    }
```

It is the very last Line that makes an error.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'SocialMedia.Models.CustomPrincipal' to 'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

What could be the problem to why it's not working.?

Comment: How do you declare `CustomPrincipal` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear, the instance you are assigning to `User` property requires instance of type `IPrincipal`, i suspect that your `CustomPrincipal` class is not inheriting from `IPrinicipal` interface, that's because you are seeing the error.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Change the last line to:</del>

```
HttpContext.Current.User = (IPrincipal)newUser;
```

**EDIT**

Make sure that `ICustomPrincipal` extends the `IPrincipal` interface.

Comment: Throws error: 
An object of type ' SocialMedia.Models.CustomPrincipal ' can not be converted to type ' System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal '

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, then there must be an error in your `CustomPrincipal` implementation or your `ICustomPrincipal` interface. Add both to your question pelase.